# Stability of a nonlinear ODE system (only existence of the limit)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I'm studying a nonlinear autonomous ODE system in several variables, $\dot{x}=f(x)$ where $f$ is a Lipschitz vector field. For the unique solution $x(t)$ that starts at $x_0$, I'd just like to say that $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)$ exists.

To do this, the only general method that I know is to find a Lyapunov function, or, in alternative, one can "work it around explicitly" and take the limit. Unfortunately, both approaches seem undoable in my case. So my question is: which other general methods/theorems can I use to prove existence of the limit above?

Comment: You might get a better response if you add the ODE you're working with. As it stands the question is too broad.

Comment: So what is the dimension of your phase space? This is crucial for answering your question. Also, it's better to share the system that you are studying — there is really no good general recommendation, especially in higher dimensions ($\geqslant 2$).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know if the solution to $\dot{x}=f(x)$ can be extended to infinity. One sufficient condition is that there exists $C>0$ s.t. 
$$\langle x,f(x)\rangle\leq C(1+\|x\|^2) \quad \forall x.$$
A classical example of  the DE that violates this condition is $\dot{x}=x^2$

Comment: No, that does not seem my question. I'm just asking whether $lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)$ exists. I mean I want to avoid for example $x_i(t)=\sin(t)$

Comment: So, you want to know if you solution can be extended to infinity **and** if any trajectory either approaches a point or grows to infinity as $t\rightarrow \infty$? In this case you should better present your ODEs as it is impossible to give some universal conditions. If you look for classes of systems that satisfy the required property, you can consider monotone systems.